# Updating Blazor EditForm's InputNumber field from Javascript

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I need to set EditForm's Input Field for some reason only using JavaScript, but i am failing to do so.

My form:

```
<EditForm Model="@form" OnValidSubmit="@(async () => await HandleValidationAsync())">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Age</label>
        <InputNumber class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="0.0" @bind-Value="@form.age" readonly></InputNumber>
</div>
 <button class="button blue" type="button" @onclick="@GetAge">Get</button>
</EditForm>

@code{

private void async Task GetAge()
    {
      bool x = await jsRun.InvokeAsync<bool>("onAgeSelected",15);

    }
}
```

on the JavaScript Side

```
window.onAgeSelected= (data) => {
     $("#age").val(data);
    return true;
};
```

When I try to access the `form.age` i am always getting null;

Comment: Check the generated HTML code

Comment: all i can see is changes in css class for modified value, as for the value itself i can't actually see even if done manually.

<div class="form-group"><!--!-->
                    <!--!--><label>Age</label>
                    <!--!--><input step="any" id="age" placeholder="0.0" readonly="" type="number" class="form-control valid"><!--!-->
                </div>